# PJSip : Not able to unhold the hold call

Tags: ios, pjsip

Getting this error while unholding a call using pjsip.

> Unable to create re-INVITE: Invalid operation (PJ_EINVALIDOP)
>   [status=70013]
>        Error hanging up call: Invalid operation (PJ_EINVALIDOP) [status=70013]

Using this code for untold

```
pj_status_t pj_wrapper_unhold_call(pjsua_call_id call_id, char deviceId, char groupId, char *token) {

    pj_status_t status;

    if (!pj_wrapper_initialized) {
        return PJ_EGONE;
    }


    status = pjsua_call_reinvite(call_id, PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
        pj_wrapper_show_error("Error hanging up call", status);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: I see this error in logs of my PJSIP based app. Did you resolve it?